# Como obter dados de um perfil do facebook através da SDK de php

Tags: php, facebook-sdk

Preciso de fazer uma aplicação cujo objetivo é obter dados do meu perfil de facebook. Preciso de obter por exemplo o nome das galerias de fotos etc.
Para simplificar tentei obter o nome através do SDK do php.
Obti um token através do website do facebook e no php ficou assim:

```
// Start the session
session_start();


require_once __DIR__ . '/facebook-sdk-v5/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => '{aqui coloco o id}',
    'app_secret' => '{aqui coloco a chave}',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
]);

$fb->setDefaultAccessToken("token gerado");


//print_r($user);

/*  // Sets the default fallback access token so we don't have to pass it to each request
$fb->setDefaultAccessToken('{EAACEdEose0cBAEikRrkW1LpHKKfVKkIsf7flezUh69DDtFV7RwoOZCdkokz6yqQ8X8GUC6OHaK3hhYN8SEZBTdTre6VGrkOKhgoCom5GHdMtCHj0V0SKTfOgZCua0419IkyCscXUuynpCUsCsCogt0HiAssV6yiaWWK7mZCS66QdLCNZAZClfX}');
*/try {
  $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name');
  //$userNode = $response->getGraphUser();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

?>
```

Quando executo este codigo recebo o seguinte erro:Graph returned an error: Invalid appsecret_proof provided in the API argument.

Alguem me consegue explicar o que está mal?
Que tipo de token devo gerar para este caso? Saliento que as alterações e obtenção de dados são apenas do meu perfil.

Comment: A mensagem de erro é o `app_secret` que ele diz está inválido, verifique se está correto.

Comment: @EduardoBreno o App secret está válida. Eu conferi isso. É o secret proof não está marcado como necessário sequer.